# Recovering files deleted by Android studio?

Tags: android-studio

I'm working on an app at the moment, and one of the final steps was to get it built and signed in Android studio.

Unfortunately I was having some problems, and one of the recommended solutions was to remove the project and start again, however when I did this it took all of my files with it, and they're not in the trash (OSX) either.

Is there anyway to recover these files, or are they lost forever? :(

Comment: Perhaps try an undelete utility for your operating system

Comment: have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55649428/3496570

Answer (score 62):

**In my case I was looking for the file named 'landing_page222.java' which I deleted one day back.**

### Following Steps can help you to find your previously deleted files in Android Studio.

#### Step 1: Right Click on the folder where you deleted the file

[image]

#### Step 2: Find option for Local History and Click Show History.

[image]

#### Step 3: Find your File from Given List.

Hopefully it will be available in Instance
[image]

#### Step 4: Copy the code back as per need.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much my friend. You really saved my 4 hours work. I recovered my deleted activity

Comment: Omg I can kiss you right now.... looking at the general history didn't show it, and nothing else worked (Ctrl-z, revert, etc)  but once I hit the local history on the specific folder like you suggested, it was there! thank you too much. Good karma coming your way!

Answer (score 35):

You can try:

- looking for those files in the file system (perhaps they are still in your Android Studio projects folder)
- looking in your OS's temp folder
- using Android Studio's history feature (right-click on the Project tab > Local History > Show history)

Comment: Thank you, looks like they're all gone, argh! :(

Comment: @Nick No backup anywhere? :(

Comment: No unfortunately, my PC is backed up constantly but I'm using my girlfriend's Macbook :( Thanks for the tips though!

Comment: Amazing: Android Studio's history saved me!
I knew which file I had lost, so I re-created it and looked at its "history" in Android Studio.

Comment: Thank you! In my case i also deleted a local branch. But i remember the name. So i created the branch again, open a local history and revert deleted files!

Comment: Thank you bro! I deleted my json data which migrate to roomdatabase. You save my time dear.

Answer (score 12):

Click whereever you want in the left frame (for example "drawable" file is ok) and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>. You are going to see "Undo delete popup" window.

And as you understand, when you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> in Android Studio, which (XML or Java) file is active, you will undo the action on that tab. So, if you click any file on the left side and press the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> combination, you will undo the action at the file structure.

Answer (score 9):

Go to View > Recent Changes > Click on the file you want to recover > Click "Revert"

Answer (score 2):

Im late but [this](https://clay-atlas.com/us/blog/2021/03/15/android-studio-en-recover-delete-file/) works. Go to the folder where u want to recover. right-click, local history. select ones you deleted and click revert. :)

Comment: Yeah, buddy. I had to do this file by file. Luckily, I had a backup from 4 months earlier. I wish knew a way to do this in a go. Or I knew how to recover from Git.